# Conditionally configure instance in StructureMap

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap

Preemptive rtfm disclaimer: StructureMap's documentation is a major version out of date, and the API it documents doesn't even exist anymore, not to say anything for the attributes marked obsolete.

I have an environment setting, that for all intents and purposes can be treated as a static application-scoped boolean.  The result of this boolean needs to control which implementation of my interface is plugged in.  The [sample documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/InstanceExpression.htm#section18) for conditionals is perfect for what I'm looking for, but none of those methods exist in 3.1.1.134 (latest in NuGet as of 9/8/2014).

I am looking for the current version of the following pseudo-syntax, and do not let "GetEnvironmentVariable" be a red herring -- it is just an example of a runtime system-wide boolean that needs to be evaluated on graph building.

```
public ConditionalInjectionRegistry : Registry 
{
    For<IBehavior>().UseConditionally(u => 
    {
        u.Conditionally(() => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("foo") == "bar")).Is<FooedBehavior>();
        u.Default.Is<NormalBehavior>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/1W2UpKlGxgw), the correct way to do this now is with a lambda inside `Use()`.

```
For<IIndexResolver>().Use("some description for diagnostics", c => {
  // and just do it all with a single anonymous lambda
});
```